# Eigenvalues of matrix product of two hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the eigenvalues of the matrix product of two Hermitian matrices are either real or appear as pairs of complex conjugates, i.e., if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then so is its complex conjugate $\overline{\lambda}$.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: For those curious, an example where the product has complex eigenvalues:
$$
\pmatrix{-1\\&1}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\begin{split}\overline{\det(AB-\lambda I)} &= \det\left[(AB-\lambda I)^*\right]  = \det(B^*A^*-\overline\lambda I) \\&= \det(BA-\overline\lambda I) = \det(AB-\overline\lambda I),\end{split}$$ where the last equality follows from the [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sylvester.27s_determinant_theorem).